# Setting up multiple domains on one Cpanel account

Tags: domains, apache, cpanel

I set up an account on Cpanel for a domain "abc.com". However, if I wanted to point the A record for "def.com" to abc's existing account, what changes would I have to make server side?

I'm aware that I can use add-on domains to accomplish, but is there a way to do this by using the above mentioned method? By pointing the A record for the 2nd domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll help explain how the add-on feature works in Cpanel, basically it edits the Apache config and makes an additional in the available sites folder that looks for the referring domain name i.e the A record. Now your host allows you could add this manually but this would be the same as using the ADDON feature, but you need to inform your server about the referring domain via the config and without this it doesn't know what Virtual Folder to use, so if you do point it.. chances are it will just return unavailable or ABC.com site is accessible though DEF.com because it they are on the same IP and ABC is the default site.

**Can't be Done Sorry**

So in other-words, no you need to use ADDON - that's how you add additional domains to cpanel accounts unless you have a multiple user cpanel account in which you just add another cpanel account and then add the domain as the main site for that account.